# Android - Debug app on phone reboot

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to reset alarms after the phone restarts.
I set up a BroadcastReceiver which starts a Service if the intent equals android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

The question is: how can I debug this? I mean, I would like to use the Android Studio debugger to see if the Service started correctly. How can I do that?